# Selecting similar records with different primary keys

Tags: vb.net

In my VB.Net program, I am trying to select entries that have the same value but have different primary keys and details. For example, in my database, I have the following records:

___PK_____LastName_____FirstName_____Details

001168_____Smith________John_________New York
001479_____Smith________John_________London
001698_____Smith________John_________Paris

I use two different/separate comboboxes for the PK and the LastName, so I populate them using two different codes (below):

```
'This is for the PK
conn.Open()
    Dim dryear As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT distinct cltaccountnum FROM tblclientinfo", conn)
    Dim dtyear As New DataTable
    dryear.Fill(dtyear)
    Me.cmbAcctNo1.DisplayMember = "cltaccountnum"
    Me.cmbAcctNo1.DataSource = dtyear
    conn.Close()

 'And this is for the Names
 conn.Open()
    Dim dryear5 As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT cltlastname FROM tblclientinfo order by cltlastname", conn)
    Dim dtyear5 As New DataTable
    dryear5.Fill(dtyear5)
    Me.cmbClientName1.DisplayMember = "cltlastname"
    Me.cmbClientName1.DataSource = dtyear5
    conn.Close()
```

And I included these codes so that whenever I select values from either comboboxes, the values of the other changes (according to the corresponding record):

```
    Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbAcctNo1.SelectedIndexChanged
    'connection string

    If cmbAcctNo1.Text <> "" Then
        conn = GetConnect()


        conn.Open()

        Dim com As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        com.CommandText = "Select * from tblclientinfo where cltaccountnum = '" & cmbAcctNo1.Text & "'"
        com.Connection = conn
        dr = com.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        cmbClientName1.Text = dr!cltlastname
        Label13.Text = dr!cltfirstname

        conn.Close()

        conn.Open()
        com.CommandText = "select * from tblpropertypayments where cltaccountnumb = '" & cmbAcctNo1.Text & "'"
        com.Connection = conn
        dr = com.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        txtUnitCode1.Text = dr!pmtLocCode

        'txtUnitCode1.Text = dr!cltunitcode
        'cmbParticulars1.Text = 
        'txtPayee1.Text = 
        'txtAmount1.Text = 
        conn.Close()

    Else
        cmbClientName1.Text = ""
        Label13.Text = ""
        txtUnitCode1.Text = ""
    End If


End Sub

 Private Sub cmbClientName1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbClientName1.SelectedIndexChanged

    If cmbClientName1.Text <> "" Then
        'connection string
        conn = GetConnect()
        conn.Open()

        Dim com As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        com.CommandText = "Select * from tblclientinfo where cltlastname = '" & cmbClientName1.Text & "'"
        com.Connection = conn
        dr = com.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        cmbAcctNo1.Text = dr!cltaccountnum
        Label13.Text = dr!cltfirstname

        conn.Close()

        conn.Open()
        com.CommandText = "select * from tblpropertypayments where cltaccountnumb = '" & cmbAcctNo1.Text & "'"
        com.Connection = conn
        dr = com.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        txtUnitCode1.Text = dr!pmtLocCode

        'cmbParticulars1.Text = 
        'txtPayee1.Text = 
        'txtAmount1.Text = 
        conn.Close()
    Else
        txtUnitCode1.Text = ""
        cmbAcctNo1.Text = ""
        Label13.Text = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

It works perfectly fine, so I don't have any issues about that other than the one I have stated above. What happens is that since, let's take the above example for this, there are three occurences of 'Smith John' on the record, I think the 'SELECT' on the comboboxes' SelectedIndexChanged events get confused, I mean, whichever 'Smith John' I select, only the first PK '001168' appears (although the other PKs appears on the combobox for PK). Is there a way to let it know that I am not addressing the same name (a similar name only, but with different details and PK) here?

Comment: You're using different column names in your SQL code to what you what you specified in your table above, so that's a great way to confuse the issue.  Is you `cltaccountnum` column the PK?  If so then why do you need to use `DISTINCT` in the query, given that all values are guaranteed to be unique?  It seems to me that you should just be performing one query that pulls back the PK and the name and then binding the one result set to both `ComboBox` controls.  That way, they will both update automatically.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to remove the `DISTINCT` in my code sample above, but I already removed it from my code. And... I think I got confused with the "...you should just be performing one query that pulls back the PK and the name and then binding the one result set to both ComboBox controls". And, yes, I just noticed that. I think I need to try combining cltlastname and cltfirstname to produce a more precise query (I think?)

Comment: I did this for the combobox' selectedindexchanged event `"select cltlastname + ', ' + cltfirstname as cltname,* from tblclientinfo where cltlastname = '" & cltname(0) & "' and cltfirstname = '" & cltname(1) & "'"` in place of the com.CommandText above (I have used a string.split named cltname() for the string) but I get an error `Invalid attempt to read when no data is present`. I tried to display cltname(0) and cltname(1) using a msgbox and it displays a value, meaning it is not empty. Why am I getting the error message?